# ReactiveCocoa send value from Model to ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I'm using MVVM architecture in my project. In my model I have my business logic and from there I am calling service methods. I have signal in my service that actually is observing one property:

```
- (RACSignal *)executing;
- (RACSignal *)executing
{
  return RACObserve(self, executing);
}
```

Property 'Executing' is NSNumber property which I need to pass all the way to viewController to show ActivityBar when my call to service is executing. So in my viewModel I have this:

```
- (RACSignal *)executing
{
  return [[self.services getRetailers] executing];
}
```

I bind that in ViewController like this:

```
RAC([UIApplication sharedApplication], networkActivityIndicatorVisible) = self.regWizardcontentViewModel.executing;
```

It is not working. I am new to this Reactive programming so I'm asking how to pass that signal correctly. At the same time, in my Model, I have a dictionary of results, I want to pass that dictionary to my ViewModel with RAC and I have no idea how it is done. I have been searching and searching for some answer. I have been stuck here for days now.

EDIT:

```
- (void)search:(NSString *)countryCode
{
   manager = [Manager sharedManager];
   manager._delegate = self;
   [manager getRetailers:countryCode];
   self.executing = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
}

- (void)manager:(Manager *)client didSuccesWithoutError:(id)responseObject
{
   self.retailer = responseObject;
   self.executing = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
   NSLog(@"Loaded successfully: %@", self.retailer);
}

- (void)manager:(Manager *)client didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   self.executing = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
   NSLog(@"Error Retrieving %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that shows how `self.executing` is actually being modified?

Comment: Create a RACSignal temporary variable for `self.regWizardcontentViewModel.executing` and log it with `NSLog("%@", signal)`, then `subscribeNext:` to it and `NSLog` the default `x` variable. Please post the output as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The following code:

```
- (RACSignal *)executing
{
  return RACObserve(self, executing);
}
```

makes no sense. You are implementing the `executing` accessor method to return a signal that sends a value whenever the object's `executing` property fires a KVO event. But the value will always be a signal that sends a value whenever the object's `executing` property fires a KVO event.